# Retrieve array from multidimension arrays in JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Following is my JSON output :

```
{
    "BILLINGINFO": [
        {
            "CUST_REQ_BILL_DATE": "15",
            "BILL_MONTH": "03",
            "CONSOLIDATION_CRITERIA": "016",
            "CONSOLIDATION_OPTION": "A",
            "SPLIT_LINES": "",
            "BILL_IN_ARREARS": "X",
            "BILL_CREATE_DATE": "02"
        }
    ],
    "DROPDOWNS": [
        {
            "FIELD": "CUST_REQ_BILL_DATE",
            "VALUE": "01",
            "TEXT": "1st of month"
        },
        {
            "FIELD": "CUST_REQ_BILL_DATE",
            "VALUE": "02",
            "TEXT": "2nd of month"
        }
   ]
}
```

I am still learming jquery and not sure how to retrive values of BILLINGINFO and DROPDOWN arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say this JSON is stored in a variable called `obj`. Then you'd use:

```
obj.BILLINGINFO
// and
obj.DROPDOWNS
```

or:

```
obj["BILLINGINFO"]
obj["DROPDOWNS"]
```

Reference: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

To loop through them, you can use something like the following (need to apply to each):

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.BILLINGINFO.length; i++) {
    var current = obj.BILLINGINFO[i];
    // Work with `current` and you can use
    // current.CUST_REQ_BILL_DATE, current.BILL_MONTH, etc.
}
```

So there's no need to use jQuery for any of this. But an option for looping is using `each`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: +1 Also, you can use `obj['BILLINGINFO']` and `obj['DROPDOWN']`.

Comment: @mellamokb True, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets . I'll still add it in

Comment: Actually, the dropdown array is meant for combobox values and I need to loop thru it. I am using this but it gives "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error :    $.each(data.dropdowns, function(index) {
                          $('#conscrit').append('<option>' +  data.dropdowns[index].TEXT + '</option>');
                        });

Comment: @user1596433 Why are you using `data.dropdowns`? It should be `data.DROPDOWNS`

Comment: Thank You Ian, that was the issue. I was so dumb to not to notice that.

Comment: @user1596433 No problem, basically everything's case-sensitive in Javascript, and this is no exception :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$.parseJson
```

function to parse it

Comment: @hop We have no way of knowing whether or not that is parsed yet due to lack of information.

Comment: @KevinB Fine.But, does this answer the question